Angular mat-checkboxes are not loading saved values
I have a checkbox that is done a little different than how it's normally done. I have one form control in my form group. When I save that formControl, it will contain an array of the checked values. The problem I'm having is that when I save and load the data, the checkboxes are not checked off? Anyone know how I can solve this?
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [formControl]="formControl">
  <div>
    @for(checkbox of checkboxes; track checkbox){
      <mat-checkbox
        [value]="checkbox.display"
        [checked]="checkbox.check"
        (change)="onChange(checkbox)"
      >
        {{ checkbox.display }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    }
  </div>
</mat-form-field>

ngOnInit() {
  this.options.forEach((element: any) => {
    let checkbox: Checkbox = {
      key: element.key,
      display: element.display,
      check: element.check
    }
    this.checkboxes.push(checkbox); 
  })
}


onChange(checkbox: any){
  checkbox.check = !checkbox.check;
  if(this.checkedBoxes.find(box => checkbox.check == false && box.key === checkbox.key)){
    this.checkedBoxes = this.checkedBoxes.filter(box => box.key !== checkbox.key); // remove
  }
  else {
    this.checkedBoxes.push(checkbox); // add 
  }

  this.formControl.setValue(this.checkedBoxes);
}

So say I have a checkbox list of these values, and I check 'apple' and 'grape'...
[
  {
    key: 'apple_id',
    display: 'Apple',
    check: false,
  },
  {
    key: 'banana_id',
    display: 'Banana',
    check: false,
  },
  {
    key: 'orange_id',
    display: 'Orange',
    check: false,
  },
  {
    key: 'grape_id',
    display: 'Grape',
    check: false,
  }
]

Then I would get something like this as the form control value:
[
  {
    key: 'apple_id',
    display: 'Apple',
    check: true,
  },
  {
    key: 'grape_id',
    display: 'Grape',
    check: true,
  }
]

And when I load the data, I just call formGroup.patchValue().

From your code, I don't see that you are using FormGroup. And I see that there is typo error checkedBoxes.

Would be great if you could explain your expected result on: "I save and load the data, the checkboxes are not checked off?". If I understand correctly, as your checkboxes didn't apply in Reactive Form, so to uncheck it you need to update the chekboxes array by setting them to false.

@YongShun Right, formGroup is set in a different component, but I'm trying not to expose too much. As for the expect result, you are correct. The checkboxes are not being applied in Reactive Form.


When You load the data After value patch with formControl.
Load data functionality use in OnInit() method.
Try to debug in api calling method

